# Implicit function theorem for one equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

The Implicit function theorem for a single equation in our textbook states that 
let F(x,y) be a function of class $C^1$ on some neighborhood of a point (a,b), for each **x** in the ball |**x**-**a**|< $r_0$ there is a unique y such that |y-b| < $r_1$

Given the function F(x,y)= ($y^2$- $x^4$)

at the point **a**= (0.5,0.25),   the conditions of the IFT hold, and we are asked to find the largest $r_1$ such that $\partial_{y}$ F(x,y)>0 for all the points in the $r_1$ neighbourhood of the point **a**

I know that  $\partial_{y}$=2y and for 2y>0, we can get y>0 and thus the inequality |y-0.25|<$r_1$, now I have restrict y to a bound but how should I find the limit for $r_1$?